# Getting OverflowError: timeout value is too large while using kafka-python producer-consumer

Tags: python, kafka-python

Well, I am trying to use Kafka-python package(1.3.2) in python to have a simple data tansfer from my producer to consumer.

Producer:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
# produce asynchronously
for _ in range(2):
    producer.send('my-topic', b'message')
    producer.flush()
producer = KafkaProducer()
```

Consumer:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
                     group_id='my-group',
                     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],fetch_min_bytes=1)
for message in consumer:
print ("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                      message.offset, message.key,
                                      message.value))

consumer = KafkaConsumer()
consumer.subscribe(["my-topic"])
```

I receive below on my consumer:

`my-topic:0:5056: key=None value=b'message'
 my-topic:0:5057: key=None value=b'message'`

But at the same time I have this error at producer:

`Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VNK736\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\kafka.py", line 364, in wrapper
    _self.close()
  File "C:\Users\VNK736\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\producer\kafka.py", line 420, in close
    self._sender.join(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\VNK736\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 1060, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock(timeout=max(timeout, 0))
  File "C:\Users\VNK736\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
OverflowError: timeout value is too large`

By default the timeout is set to `NONE`, and is being set to `999999999` in `Kafka.py`. I am unable to figure out the param to pass this timeout in KafkaProducer - in my producer code.

Has anyone faced this problem? Or could anyone help me in this direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issues are probably stemming from the fact that you are on 32 bit windows. From what I can tell, there is no explicit support for 32 bit within the kafka-python code.

From what I can tell, your implementation looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on py3 docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.TIMEOUT_MAX), if timeout argument is too large (greater than TIMEOUT_MAX) OverflowError will be thrown.